# converting html text to an image with php

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

what's the best way to convert a text embedded in a html tag to an image using php keeping the style written in the html tag ? for example :

convert :

```
<span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-size: xx-large;"><font class="Apple-style-span" color="#F4A460">Stack </font><font class="Apple-style-span" color="#800000">Overflow</font></span>
```

into :
[image]

is there any class for it ? or should I explode it and read the tags one by one ? any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might want to have a look at [Painty](http://www.rabuser.info/painty.php#english). Although it isn't exactly what you're looking for because you'll have to feed it an array of options, it should be a good resource on which you can expand.

Not sure if you also want to render the font(s) being used in your HTML snippet, but if you do, you would also have to get all the commonly used web-fonts and put them all in a folder from where the script can read.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeahhh awesome ! that's by far the best one, at least gonna save me the headache of writing the class myself !

Comment: @hakim-sina glad to be of help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

With PHP GD Library support, yes:

http://visionmasterdesigns.com/tutorial-convert-text-into-transparent-png-image-using-php/ (font/size technique included)

http://corpocrat.com/2009/06/23/php-script-to-convert-textemail-address-to-image/

Comment: yeah I know how to convert a simple text to image, but what I need is more complex ... I need something that reads the style in the tag and applies it to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list

The project is centered around html to pdf using the webkit engine, but there are also binaries and source for html to image. It's an external binary though, so might not be useful to you in your use-case.

Otherwise I would look into imagemagick.